# Web components with SSR getting disappeared (StencilJS + SvelteKit)

Tags: server-side-rendering, web-component, sveltekit, stenciljs, hydration

1. We have created a simple boilerplate stenciljs component.
   a.  Published it as npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/stencil-ssr-poc
   [image]
2. Created a boilerplate Sveltkit application.
   a.  Github Repo: https://github.com/nimit-nagarro/ssr-poc/tree/master
   b.  Consumed the npm package in the application via npm install.
   [image]

(Working fine with CSR)
c.  Tried to render the same component at the server side. For this added the hooks.server.ts file code.
[image]

Flickering is there on the screen. Component renders and disappears (reloading within a sec)
On further analysis, found that class=”hydrated” gets removed from the component. If added manually in Developer tools (for testing). It works.